# Fire Resistant Bag/Wrap for Internal Rechargeable Li-ion Batteries

Tags: batteries

I am making an internal 4s8p 18650 rechargeable li-ion battery pack for a medical device, and for safety reasons, would like to encapsulate the batteries inside a fire resistant bag or wrap.

I've noticed that there many options out there for [fire resistant bags](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=fire+retardant+bag+for+batteries&crid=16PBTNDL9IYBC&sprefix=fire+retardant+battery+bag%2Caps%2C139&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-a-p_1_26) and [PVC heat shrink wraps](https://www.batteryspace.com/PVC-Heat-Shrink-Wrap-Tube.aspx).
The bags are definitely bulkier and I wonder if any device manufacturer actually put such bags around the device's internal batteries.

Are heat shrink wraps enough for safety's sake? And how about [kapton tape](https://bertech.com/product/1-in-wide-x-36-yards-long-1-mil-thick-kapton-tape/?gclid=CjwKCAiAt9z-BRBCEiwA_bWv-Pai6xPQU3f6uDGbV-G9hqI9Vx96aZgeOKIhelA2iup7UbsQVCzv-BoCDY4QAvD_BwE)? If so, would the normal [thermo tec heat barriers](https://www.summitracing.com/parts/the-13500?seid=srese1&gclid=CjwKCAiAt9z-BRBCEiwA_bWv-E1lOlqjrWKA2jWvUlEnMsGCrFfmKUbJIWGJNnSByPnCSydxKgVB6xoCTncQAvD_BwE) work? They seem to be stronger than PVCs.

Sorry for the naive questions. Hope someone can pour some knowledge on me!

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to protect the batteries in case you device is exposed to fire, or do you want to prevent the batteries in your device from setting fire to their surroundings? The bags will help (a little) in the former case, but there not a lot you can do that's practical in the latter ...

Comment: I would get a safer chemistry than li-ion for medical devices, since cost isn't much of a factor anyway.

Comment: @brhans thanks for the question! probably both... as well as for preventing chemical leak

Comment: @dandavis can you expand more on "cost isn't much of a factor anyway"? as far as i know lifeo4 is much  more expensive than li-ion. thank you:)

Comment: unlike consumer goods, medical devices are made in low volumes and have a very high purchase price, so there's not the same penny-pinching motivation. Plus, everything medical is supposed to be top-notch (certified parts) and most importantly, safe under all operating conditions.

Comment: @dandavis In other words, if it's for a medical device then the OP shouldn't be cheap.

Comment: @DKNguyen: I think "amateur" and "medical devices" don't go well together because the actual design and building of a medical device is a small fraction of the overall effort and cost to market a device. It takes _teams_ to get all the bases covered. There's some tension here, we also want to make devices available where they can help, like making a DIY mechanical bag squeezer available where a medical ventilator isn't. But in short: OP knows there's a major problem with the product, and is trying to patch it. You simply can't do that with medical devices; fix the root issue.